# Swift - resetting vc in nav controller that is embedded in tab bar

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, reset

I have a `customerViewController` that has a simple a form. When the user presses submit, a segue is triggered and another view appears. The problem occurs when the user goes back to the `customerViewController` and finds all of the old information still there. I could simply reset the form fields, but what I'd really like is to find a way to reset the entire VC. From what I've learned so far, the way to reset a vc that hasn't been pushed is to remove it and then add it back.

`customerViewController` is the initial view controller in a navigation controller which is embedded in a tab bar controller. I have a `tabBarController` class that is a `UITabBarControllerDelegate`. This is where I call:

```
override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {  
   if item.tag == 2 {   //This is the tab with my navigation controller
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CustomerVCID")
        var viewcontrollers = self.navigationController?.viewControllers

        viewcontrollers?.removeFirst()
        viewControllers?.insert(vc, at: 0)
        self.navigationController?.setViewControllers(viewcontrollers!, animated: true) 
}
```

The problem with my code is that `navigationController?.viewControllers` is nil in the code above. I can reference `viewControllers` which gives me a list of tab bar viewControllers, but I'm not sure how to get from there to the navigation controller.

I guess my question is, assuming that I'm on the right track, how do I reference the view controllers in my navigation controller?

Comment: As i read your comment in the answer below. You can always reach into the navigationControllers viewController stack and remove / append a new one

Comment: That sounds like exactly what I'd like to do. I just have to figure out how to get past the tab bar controller and into the navigation controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, I was over-complicating things by trying to access `navigationController.viewControllers` or `tabBarController.viewControllers`. All I needed was `viewControllers` which is a property of `UITabBarController` that contains an array of the controllers associated with each tab:

```
override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
    if item.tag == 2 {  //tab with navigation controller
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vcon = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CustomerVCID")

        for viewcontroller in viewControllers! {
            if let vc = viewcontroller as? UINavigationController {
                vc.viewControllers.removeFirst()
                vc.viewControllers.insert(vcon, at: 0)
                vc.setViewControllers(vc.viewControllers, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reset your form values in vc inside the `viewWillAppear(_:)`,

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
       //clear the textfields, textviews values etc. here. 
    }
}
```

Comment: That's true, I could just clear each of the form fields. But they all have titles with animated constraints and that would take a little work to reset properly. Which is why I'm hoping there's a way to get a new instance of that controller with each visit.